# Шифрование медиаконтента

Tags: шифрование

Поясню, на яндекс диске открыли безлимитное хранилище для закачанных фото и видео.
Я думаю хранить там данные полученные с камер видеонаблюдения.
Но не хочу что бы кто нибудь мог просмотреть.
Вот и интересует вопрос, существуют ли приложения для шифрования, которые шифруют видео,
фото и музыку причем эти файлы открыть можно (если например мы зашифровали видео, оно открывается как видео, но вместо снятого камерой ты увидишь белый шум)
А что бы посмотреть оригинал нужен ключ.

Как я предполагаю будет выглядеть примерный способ шифрования видео. Делим картинку на сто частей 10*10 и на каждую часть накладываем определенный фильтр. Видео после этого конечно будет больше занимать места, но понять что происходит на видео без ключа будет невозможно

Comment: Существуют такие системы. Называются "современная криптография".

Comment: А вы уверены, что в случае шифрования режим безлимита будет работать? Как я понимаю, Яндекс собирается получить профит от того, что куча пользователей будет хранить у него контент.

Comment: Но формально то это видео. Просто записан белый шум. Может телевизор ненастроенный снимал?

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что кто-то создал уже такое. Что бы вместо видео был шум. Видео-кодеки не могут так работать.

Comment: @polsok Насколько я понимаю видеокодирование, зашифровать видеопоток так, чтобы он выглядел без дешифровки белым шумом, возможно. НО! Результат будет больше исходника даже не в разы!

Comment: @Zergatul,почему? Если мы берем несжатое видео, то там мы можем обрабатывать каждый пиксель по отдельности. Ну а сжатым видео хорошо я согласна пусть будет не белый шум, а например будет видно как на плохо настроенном телевизоре.

Comment: видео -> байты -> шифрованые байты -> видео | обратно. Проблемы?)

Comment: @AndrioSkur проблемы в том, что кодирование идет с потерей информации. Ошибка в 1 бите, и блочный шифр декодирует в рандомный набор байт.

Comment: @polsok Так не бывает, нужно учитывать внутреннее устройство сжатого видео-потока и то, как работает видео-кодек. На практике это будет очень сложно сделать. А практическое применение сложно придумать, кроме вашего.

Comment: В чем проблема взять кодек без сжатия?

Answer (score 2):

Не слышал про бесплатный безлимит для фото и видео у них.
Лучший путь - выполнять шифрование после процедуры сжатия с потерями. И не подвергать шифрованию заголовочные данные, чтобы сохранить возможность воспроизведения видео. Я вот выбрал внедрение шифрования в некоторые шаги энтропийного кодирования CAVLC в H.264-видео. Энтропийное кодирование (сжатие без потерь) присутствует во многих кодеках, так что можно перенести опыт и на другие кодеки. В итоге видео можно воспроизводить, будет чуть ли не однотонная картинка. При этом плеер сталкивается с недопустимыми кодами, которые просто игнорирует. Вероятно это сделано для того, чтобы можно было хоть как-то воспроизводить поврежденные файлы.
В любом случае, я подозреваю, что хранилище перекодирует видео, так что возможность обратного восстановления потеряется. Хотя может быть и нет, если сразу загрузить видео в том формате, в котором оно у них хранится.

Comment: Про безлимит слышал, но не очень уверен. Скорее всего речь идёт об автоматической загрузке фото и видео с телефона. Теоретически можно пытаться так и камеру упихать, хотя вряд ли они не заметят, что объём растёт.